# How to define the "ß" character for Calligra font

Tags: fonts, babel, calligra

I'm trying to write some text in german and spanish using babel and the font calligra. I have found out that when it comes to the "ß" character, the outputs is actually "e" (see words in red). Is there any way to include or define a calligraphic form of this "ß" character, that is not "ss"? I wouldn't want the readers to think that some words were misspelled.

A minimal working example is shown below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,final]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=10.5cm, top=4mm, left=8mm, right=8mm, bottom=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[german,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgothic}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage[protrusion]{microtype}


\begin{document}
\calligra


\selectlanguage{german}{
Weit hinten, hinter den Wortbergen, fern der Länder Vokalien und Konsonantien leben die Blindtexte. Abgeschieden wohnen Sie in 
Buchstabhausen an der Küste des Semantik, eines {\color{red}{großen}} Sprachozeans. Ein kleines Bächlein namens Duden {\color{red}{fließt}} 
durch ihren Ort und versorgt 
sie mit den nötigen Regelialien.}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\selectlanguage{spanish}{Bendito el varón que se fía 
en jehová, y cuya confianza es jehová. porque él será como el árbol plantado junto a las aguas, que junto a la 
corriente echará sus raíces, y no verá cuando viniere el calor, sino que su hoja estará verde; y en el año de sequía no se fatigará, ni 
dejará de hacer fruto.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your claim that `the output is actually "e"` under XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX  isn't quite correct. What's happening is, rather, that the `ß` glyph isn't produced *at all*.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xetex or luatex (it means hyphenation would be wrong with xetex for example)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Package `inputenc` is deactivated with recent LaTeX:

```
Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
```

Therefore, `ß` is not active and mapped to `\ss`. It directly addresses the slot of the font `callig15.pfb` that is encoded in `T1` font encoding. However, the position of `ß` in Unicode and `T1` differs, the former is 223 (U+00DF), the latter is 255 (0xFF). At position 223, font Calligra does not have a glyph, therefore the missing sharp s.

Workaround: The sharp s can be made active:

```
\documentclass[10pt,final]{article}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=10.5cm,
  top=4mm, left=8mm, right=8mm, bottom=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[german,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[protrusion]{microtype}

\catcode`\ß=\active
\defß{\ss}

\begin{document}
\calligra

\selectlanguage{german}{
Ein {\color{red}{großer}} Sprachozean.
Das Bächlein Duden {\color{red}{fließt}} durch ihren Ort.}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Generate and use OpenType font

The copyright of the font `callig15.pfb`:

> Copyright 1992 Peter Vanroose, 1999 S. Dachian You may freely use,
>   modify and/or distribute this file, as long as this copyright notice
>   is retained

Therefore, it should be allowed to generate the font in OpenType format with the fix for the width of `ß`. Package `calligra` redefines `\ss` to append a `\kern-.22em`.

This can be done with [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/), either interactively or by a small Python script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import fontforge

font = fontforge.open('callig15.pfb')
glyph = font['germandbls']
glyph.width -= .22 * font.em

font.generate('callig15.otf')
```

The generated font `callig15.otf` can be stored in the current directory or a TDS location. Example for TeX Live and shell `bash`:

```bash
export TDS=`kpsewhich -expand-var \\$TEXMFLOCAL`
echo $TDS
mkdir -p $TDS/fonts/opentype/public/calligra
cp callig15.pfb $TDS/fonts/opentype/public/calligra/
mktexlsr $TDS
```

Then the font can be used with LuaTeX/XeTeX. It is scaled as in package `calligra`. Because the scaling also affects the inter word space, it is
reversed for the space.

```
\documentclass[10pt,final]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[protrusion]{microtype}

\newfontface\calligra{CALLIG15}[Scale=1.44, WordSpace=.7]

\begin{document}
\calligra

Ein {\color{red}{großer}} Sprachozean.
Das Bächlein Duden {\color{red}{fließt}} durch ihren Ort.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\newunicodechar` so to map `ß` to `\ss`, which in turn will be mapped to the right glyph.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[german,spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ß}{\ss}

\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage*}{german}
Weit hinten, hinter den Wortbergen, fern der Länder Vokalien 
und Konsonantien leben die Blindtexte. Abgeschieden wohnen Sie in 
Buchstabhausen an der Küste des Semantik, eines \textcolor{red}{großen} 
Sprachozeans. Ein kleines Bächlein namens Duden \textcolor{red}{fließt} 
durch ihren Ort und versorgt sie mit den nötigen Regelialien.
\end{otherlanguage*}

\bigskip

Bendito el varón que se fía en jehová, y cuya confianza es jehová. 
porque él será como el árbol plantado junto a las aguas, que junto a la 
corriente echará sus raíces, y no verá cuando viniere el calor, sino 
que su hoja estará verde; y en el año de sequía no se fatigará, ni 
dejará de hacer fruto.

\bigskip

\calligra

\begin{otherlanguage*}{german}
Weit hinten, hinter den Wortbergen, fern der Länder Vokalien 
und Konsonantien leben die Blindtexte. Abgeschieden wohnen Sie in 
Buchstabhausen an der Küste des Semantik, eines \textcolor{red}{großen} 
Sprachozeans. Ein kleines Bächlein namens Duden \textcolor{red}{fließt} 
durch ihren Ort und versorgt sie mit den nötigen Regelialien.
\end{otherlanguage*}

\bigskip

Bendito el varón que se fía en jehová, y cuya confianza es jehová. 
porque él será como el árbol plantado junto a las aguas, que junto a la 
corriente echará sus raíces, y no verá cuando viniere el calor, sino 
que su hoja estará verde; y en el año de sequía no se fatigará, ni 
dejará de hacer fruto.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You seem to believe that `\selectlanguage{german}` takes the German text as a braced argument: it's not true. I fixed the usage.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the `calligra` font package handles both `\ss` and `ß` correctly under pdfLaTeX but not under either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. More specifically, the `ß` isn't produced at all.

If you need to use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX along with the `calligra` package, I suggest you replace all instances of `ß` with `\ss{}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,final]{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi\fi
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=10.5cm, 
            vmargin=4mm, hmargin=8mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[protrusion]{microtype}

\begin{document}
\calligra
\textrm{LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX produce:}

\textcolor{red}{gro\ss en} \textcolor{red}{flie\ss t} 

\textcolor{blue}{großen} \textcolor{blue}{fließt}
\end{document}
```